# Information/Information`InformationValueForm using Full- or InputForm

Tags: output-formatting, message-coding, usage-messages, information-function

I have a problem with the build-in `Information` function for user-defined symbols with custom *StandardForm* in Mathematica 12.1.1.0:

For example with the function definitions

```
ClearAll[CM];
CM[1, a__] := CM[a]
CM /: Format[CM[a_, b___], StandardForm] := Row[{a, b}, " "]
CM::usage = "CM";
```

the query `Information[CM]` results in:

[image: Result of Information[CM]]

The definitions in the output are formatted using *StandardForm* without even displaying it correctly. The same problem occurs when one defines *UpValues*. At this point this makes the Information box just unreadable but it gets worse when using `InterpretationBox`. With

```
ClearAll[CM];
CM[1, a__] := CM[a]
CM /: Format[CM[a_, b___], StandardForm] := With[{box = ToBoxes[Row[{a, b}," "]]},
    RawBoxes[InterpretationBox[RowBox[{box}], CM[a, b]]]
];
CM::usage = "CM";
```

A call to `Information[CM]` results in an infinite recursion and several warnings and errors:

[image: Result of Information[CM] with InterpretationBox]

Inspecting the `FullForm` of the results of `Information[CM]` reveals

```
InformationData[Association[
    ...
    Rule["DownValues",Information`InformationValueForm[DownValues,CM,List[RuleDelayed[CM[1,Pattern[a,BlankSequence[]]],CM[a]]]]],
    ...
    Rule["FormatValues",Information`InformationValueForm[FormatValues,CM,List[RuleDelayed[MakeBoxes[CM[Pattern[a,Blank[]],Pattern[b,BlankNullSequence[]]],StandardForm],Format[With[List[Set[box,ToBoxes[Row[List[a,b]," "]]]],RawBoxes[InterpretationBox[RowBox[List[box]],CM[a,b]]]],StandardForm]]]]],
    ...
]]
```

and with it the internal and of course undocumented function `...InformationValueForm` which is used to output the found definitions.

Is there a way to configure or manipulate `Information` or the underlying `InformationValueForm` to display the function definitions using *Full-* or *InputForm*? I was able to manipulate the FullForm output by converting the arguments of `RuleDelayed` inside `InformationValueForm` to Strings but I  was not able to attach this fix to `Information` or `InformationValueForm`.

I do not understand the design decision behind using *StandardForm* in the output of `Information` for user-defined functions and the whole situation is basically a bug in my opinion. The real issue are the infinite recursions and errors for more involved formatting functions which can crash the kernel and/or front-end. I tend to document my functions and I sometimes like to use `Information` to remind myself of argument order. The rather unsatisfying workaround which I am currently using is to disable `Information` for my formatted functions using UpValues:

```
CM /: Information[CM, opts___] := CM::usage;
```

This way I at least have access to the usage message but definitions, options and all the other `Information`-data is not accessible using this workaround.

Comment: Please read the [tags:bugs] info. It is a special tag applied only after community consensus.

Comment: For clarity, what does your expected/hoped-for output look like? Is it what you showed in your answer? If so, consider updating the question to reflect this.

Comment: By the way, is the bounty also intended for people to help mark this as a bug?

Comment: Well the intend behind the bounty was to draw attention (which did not work that great I guess). What I was looking for was and is a way " to display the function definitions using Full- or InputForm" in the output of information. The fix I presented below is not really this and requires some more adjustments to work properly when user functions are cross referenced/ call each other. Since I did not know about the specialty of the "bug" tag I did not post the bounty to get help with tagging it as a bug here. If I find the time I will send a bug report to Wolfram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my question in the source code of several Mathematica core functions. Using the immensely helpful function `` GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions `` on e.g. `InterpolatingFunction` (or any other core function using `` BoxForm` ArrangeSummaryBox `` for its formatted output) reveals the protected kernel function/variable `` BoxForm`UseIcons ``. This seems to be a dynamic variable related to `BoxForm` which is false for the boxes generated by `Information`. The following code allows for custom formatting in the notebook but not in the output of `Information` (including `?` and `??`) and other environments with `` BoxForm`UseIcons=False ``:

```
MakeBoxes[..., StandartForm] /; BoxForm`UseIcons := ...
```

[image: Fix information output using BoxForm`UseIcons]

Attaching the custom formatting to `MakeBoxes` instead of `Format` and checking the variable `` BoxForm`UseIcons `` does the trick and answers my question to my satisfaction. This solution is by far the better solution compared to my previous answer and the method of choice for at least some core functions with fancy formatted output. I posted a this new answer since the solution strategy differs from the previous one.

It is a pity that this is not documented alongside `Format` or `MakeBoxes` or even an option or default of those functions.

Answer (score 0):

I found a somewhat feasible solution based on UpValues on the problematic user methods/symbols e.g.:

```
ClearAll[CM];
CM[1, a__] := CM[a]
CM /: Format[CM[a_, b__], StandardForm] := Row[{a, b}, " "]
CM /: Format[CM[a_], StandardForm] := a

Unprotect[CMinfo]; ClearAll[CMinfo];
CMinfo /: Format[CMinfo, StandardForm] = "CM";
Attributes[CMinfo] = {Protected, Constant};
CM /: Information`InformationValueForm[val_, CM, exp_List] := 
 With[{s = ReleaseHold[Hold[exp] /. CM -> CMinfo]}, 
  Information`InformationValueForm[val, CMinfo, s]]
CM /: Information`InformationValueForm[FormatValues, CM, exp_List] := 
 With[{s = {Skeleton[Length[exp]]}}, 
  Information`InformationValueForm[val, CMinfo, s]]
CM::usage = "CM::usage";
```

which results in the output

[image: Information]

The symbol `CMinfo` is used in `...InformationValueForm[...]` instead of `CM` to prevent formatting in the definitions. The output for `FormatValues` is still formatted and therefore not very informative so I inserted a placeholder instead. Maybe with a bit more work one could get the `FormatValues` working as well.

This approach works well enough for me but I am still rather unpleased with the necessity for such measures. The `Information[...]` method should work out of the box on valid user functions. So I am still in favor of calling the whole mess a bug but thank you to @Michael E2 for pointing out in the comments under the question that the tag 'bug' requires vetting. I did not read the tag description and used it wrong - sorry for that.

Note that both `Information[CM]` and `??CM` work as intended when modifying `...InformationValueForm[...]`, which is surprsingly not the case for the fix put forward in my question (setting `CM /: Information[CM] := CM::usage`).

[image: Information set using UpValues]

The special input forms `?` and `??` are not only special by name but also special because they circumvent UpValues for `Information` which again just sounds very unreasonable to me.