# Use Format while still being able to copy-paste the underlying representation

Tags: formatting

Suppose that I have a Head `A` that appears pretty often in my code and, in order to make my outputs look nicer, I define

```
Format[A[x_]]:=Subscript[A,x];
```

Now if $A_1$ appears in the output and I try to copy and paste it, the result of the paste is `Subscript[A,1]` rather than `A[1]`.

I would like to find a way such that the data copied to clipboard is not the representation of the expression, but rather its underlying structure. Just like when, for example, I assign it to a variable.

Comment: Prior to copy and paste, convert the cell (or a duplicate of the cell) to `InputForm`

Comment: That doesn't seem to do what I need. The cell becomes `Subscript[A,1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a minor adjustment using this code:

```
Format[A[x_]] := Interpretation[ 
   Subscript[A, x], A[x]];
```

which does what you expect with copy/paste.

There are other ways to get fancy with Mathematica which can do a lot more, but
this code seems to do what is required.

However, if you want the pasted form to be the "raw" form, you can do that with a slight tweak using `Defer[]` which was
designed for this purpose. Code follows:

```
Format[A[x_]] := Interpretation[ 
   Subscript[A, x], (Defer@A)[x]];
```

Comment: All the answers were equivalent, but I'm accepting yours because of its simplicity.

Comment: Also, the behavior I was going for is slightly different as I wanted to have that the object pasted was the raw form of the expression. This, however, is easily obtained by doing "Copy As > Input Text" (I'm leaving this here for anyone else who might need it.)

Comment: Although I should point out that this tends to give problems when you use those expressions in some functions and then you call `?thatFunction`. I am still looking into it.

Comment: @MannyC I have given a tweak which solves your "raw form" problem.

Comment: I'd suggest an edit as per @N0va answer. Replace `Interpretation` by `safeInterpretation` where `safeInterpretation[formatted, raw] := If[BoxForm\`UseIcons, Interpretation[formatted, raw], <whatever you want to show in the Information output.>]`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes) and create a [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) that controls both display and interpretation:

```
A /: MakeBoxes[A[x_], StandardForm] := TemplateBox[
    {MakeBoxes[x]},
    "A",
    DisplayFunction -> Function[SubscriptBox["A", #]],
    InterpretationFunction -> Function[RowBox[{"A", "[", #, "]"}]]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

```
ToInterpretationBox[raw_][formatted_]:=With[{box=ToBoxes[formatted]},InterpretationBox[RowBox[{box}],raw]]
A/:MakeBoxes[A[x_],StandardForm]/;BoxForm`UseIcons:=ToInterpretationBox[A[x]][Subscript[A,x]];
```

which sets up an `InterpretationBox` for `A` and this `InterpretationBox` is copied by default. Using `Copy as -> Input Text` one can copy the input form. If one really wants the behavior OP described I would recommend the approach presented by Carl Woll in his answer to this question.

As a warning when setting up custom output formats: I would recommend using

```
MakeBoxes[..., StandartForm] /; BoxForm`UseIcons := ...
```

related to the discussion in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/231387/ the undocumented condition `` BoxForm`UseIcons `` prevents formatting in certain environments especially when using `Information`, which might otherwise lead to serious problems: the least of which is lost readability in the documentation the worst are serious errors, when one does not exclude Patterns when setting up the formatting.